# change the final number of the permalink by +1 php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, permalinks, slug

these days I wonder how I can change the final permalink number of my posts by +1, i found this code on the net, but it needs to be changed someone help me?

```
// Get all posts
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
));

$posts = $query->get_posts();

foreach ($posts as $post) {

    // Get permalink
    $url = $post->post_name;

    // old url
    $old_url = array(
        'http://localhost:8888/site/testpermalink-1/',
        'http://localhost:8888/site/testpermalink-1/',
        'http://localhost:8888/site/testpermalink-7/',
        'http://localhost:8888/site/testpermalink-4/',
        'http://localhost:8888/site/testpermalink-36/',

    );

    // Replacement
    //$replacement = '';

    // Replace url
    //$new_url = str_replace($old_url, $replacement, $url);
    

    // Prepare arguments
    $args = array(
        'ID' => $post->ID,
        'post_name' => $new_url,
    );

    // Update post
    wp_update_post( $args );
}
```

}

I would like this list to be changed with the final number +1, so this list after editing should be:

```
$new_url = array(
    'http://localhost:8888/site/testpermalink-2/',
    'http://localhost:8888/site/testpermalink-2/',
    'http://localhost:8888/site/testpermalink-8/',
    'http://localhost:8888/site/testpermalink-5/',
    'http://localhost:8888/site/testpermalink-37/',

);
```

however then these permalink should be automatically saved after you change them.

Answer (score 0):

Permalink is the post_name in database, sometimes called "slug".

You can do something similar:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    // split it into pieces, dividing by - character
    $pieces = explode('-', $post->post_name);
    //replace last piece adding 1
    $pieces[array_key_last($pieces)] = (int)$pieces[array_key_last($pieces)] + 1;
    //restore pieces
    $post->post_name = implode('-', $pieces);
    wp_update_post( $post );
}
```

WARNING: array_key_last function exists from PHP 7.0!

Comment: thanks Full, but in this way I am going to modify all the post_name of the database?

Comment: Yes, filtered by what you put in the constructor of WP_Query!

Comment: ah ok, because I just wanted to change the post_name that I put in an array not all, can you give me a tip on how to do it? thank you so much

Comment: You could try to filter based on the post_name, so something similar to WP_Query(['post_name'=>['testpermalink-1','testpermalink-2']])